# API for Telnet Client in C++

Tags: networking, c++, client, telnet

My apologies if this is not the right place to ask my question. I am communicating with a telnet server on my local network. Please note that, the communication is working fine using the telnet command in my Ubuntu.

My goal is to send commands and receive output from the telnet server. However, I do not want to reinvent the wheel by writing a telnet client. Thus, I am looking for an API using which I can use the telnet client inside my C++ project.

It seems that Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS comes with the netkit-telnet (0.17-41.2build1) package, which provides the telnet client. However, I could not find a way to use it in an external program. The package suggests using telnet-SSL or Kerberized TELNET clients as the current implementation exchanges username and passwords in clear text. However, there is no such requirement in my case. Moreover, all the commands and responses are in plain text ASCII.

I can think of creating a pipe on telnet command using C++ to send and receive data. But I am afraid this design could lead to the slow performance of my code. Overall, I want to send/receive data as fast as possible.

Therefore, please suggest a standard library or API for using the existing telnet client in C++.

Comment: Check out this thread on the Raspberry Pi forum. That is C code not C++, but the needed changes should be trivial (the plain C might just work, but a few changes would make it proper C++) https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=227026

Comment: @cocomac: Thank you very much. I am looking into it. Meanwhile I also found famous `curl` library supports telnet and provides C API. https://curl.se/libcurl/